# Почему бот отправляет сообщение, хотя по условия не должен этого происходить Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, datetime

```
@tasks.loop(hours = 18.0 )
async def sob():
    c = today.weekday() # Проверяет день недели(изменить weekday) и написать такие же функции
    if c == 5 or 6 :
            channel = await bot.fetch_channel(926201516963029014)
            await channel.send('Сегодня будет собрание')
    else :
        pass
```

В теории бот должен сначала поверить день недели и только потом скидывать сообщение, но он скидывает его сразу же, хотя по дате не подходит(сегодня понедельник следовательно с = 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас неверно реализована проверка дня недели: для проверки нескольких условий через ИЛИ нужно оформлять код следующим образом: `if cond1 or cond2`, где `condN` — условие. Я предполагаю, что Вы хотели проверить равенство переменной `c` с `5` или `6`, однако Ваша формула будет трактована так:

```
if (c == 5) or (6)
```

т.е. `если c == 5 или 6`. При передаче любого численного ненулевого литерала подразумевается `True`, так что имеем в итоге

```
if c == 5 or True
```

а это всегда равно `True`, невзирая на `c`.

Стоит переписать данное условие таким образом:

```
@tasks.loop(hours = 18.0 )
async def sob():
    c = today.weekday() # Проверяет день недели(изменить weekday) и написать такие же функции
    if c == 5 or c == 6: # 6 меняем на c == 6
            channel = await bot.fetch_channel(926201516963029014)
            await channel.send('Сегодня будет собрание')
    else :
        pass
```

Теперь код действительно проверяет равенство переменной с 5 или 6 (скорее всего, субботой и воскресеньем?), и код будет работать только в эти дни, а не всегда.

P.S. Если хочется побаловаться, то можно использовать условие типа `if c in [5, 6]` :)